# Android development guides

Tags: google-app-engine, android

I am new to android development.I have created  a couple of wallpaper apps.I am very much interested in android.Since i do not have any resources to study or know about more advanced concepts in android development.
Can anybody please suggest me any advanced android pdf books?Please share any links available.

I know this forum helps incredibly well for android developers to share their knowledge.
This forum is full of experts in android development and i hope anyone will help.Please help me to pursue my knowledge in android.

Comment: Have you checked out the [training pages](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html) at the developer web site?

Comment: @TedHopp No. I dont know about this. I will Check it out.Thank you for your instant reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also pretty new to Android and what I have found helpful to me (so far) is:

- http://developer.android.com/training/index.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/
- http://www.newthinktank.com/videos/android-video-tutorial/

If you are also new to Java, I would highly recommend to read "Thinking In Java" by Bruce Eckel